# mysql random value change

Tags: mysql, apache, timer, random

I have a database in mysql with 1 table composed by 5 fields.
Two of these fields are FLOAT and generated by RAND function; now i want to change these values each x time, for example numeric values have to change every 0.01 s to simulate a financial market.
Is there a method to do this thing?
Thanks

Comment: How does a random number every 0.01 seconds simulate the financial market? You'd get crazy fluctuation. Of course, if it's just to test the load of the database then I get it.

Comment: i want to set 0.01 s only to test the cpu and ram usage of my pc; then i will turn the timer to 3 or 4 s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to do it directly inside the database, that could help :
[Schedule Tasks using Events on MySQL](http://pcquest.ciol.com/content/Developer/2008/108040504.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to change these values directly in table? It will be a huge load on database to update it every 0.01s. Maybe you can do it server-side, or maybe event with Javascript?

Comment: I'm interested in server-side solution because i have created a client in Flex which have to talk to a remote server which has to change numeric values.
Can you explain me how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like you're just testing, you could do this in a shell script. Something like this:

```
while [ true ] do 
  mysql -sse "update test.rand_table set rand_column = rand();"
  sleep 0.01
done
```

A stored proc would probably be more efficient since it could re-use the same connection:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.UPDATE_RANDOM_TABLE $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test.UPDATE_RANDOM_TABLE ()
BEGIN
  WHILE TRUE
  DO
    update test.rand_Table set rand_column = rand();
    select sleep(0.01);
  END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```